# <--- and <-> in pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I am not from cs background and I am trying to make sense of what is used for what. In pseudocode I see a lot of this:

```
for i <---  1 to n-1 do
j <--- find-Min(A,i,n)
A[j] <-> A[i]
end for
```

What are `<---` and `<->` used to refer to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<---` means "assign the right-hand side to the left-hand side" (it is somewhat strange to see this used in the `for` case, as it might easily have been omitted there).

`<->` means "swap". A[j] value is swapped with A[i].

**EDIT**:

It just occurred to me that the first line might be missing `i` and should instead read:

```
for i <---  1 to n-1 do
```

This becomes a legitimate use case of `<---` described above: `i` is assigned values from `1` to `n-1` sequentially, and the loop body (down to `end for`, which denotes the end of loop) is executed for each of these `i` values.

Answer (score 4):

There's nowhere close to universal agreement about the notation used in pseudocode.

In this case I'd guess that `<---` means "assign the right side to the left side", and `<->` means 'swap the right and left sides."

In the first case, however, I think you're missing a character. It's probably supposed to be:

```
for i <--- 1 to n-1 do
```

So it's a normal `for` loop that would be written as:

```
for i = 1 to n-1
```

in BASIC, or:

```
for (i=1; i<n; i++)
```

in a C-like language.

Answer (score 1):

#### Left arrow for assignment

is used to make it obvious that the variable receives a new value, e.g.

```
for i <- 1 to n-1 do
```

I have seen this in:

- mainly pseudo code;
- R, S, Scala and OCaml;
- with an own left arrow symbol in APL.

#### Left-right-arrow for swapping elements

is also used to make the operation obvious in a symbolic way.

I can't think of anything but pseudo code right now.